# Where is the downloaded Keras dataset stored?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I run `from keras.datasets import mnist` and `mnist.load_data()` to downloaded the MNIST data. But I want to know where they are stored. I am using Windows 10 and Anaconda, and I looked into here:-

```
C:\Users\My_User_Name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\datasets
```

I can find the text file `mnist.py`, but I can't find the downloaded data. Where should I find them? Many thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c60f1e19dceacf77749a6215b1fc77f758f46327/keras/datasets/mnist.py#L14) for that function, we see it uses [`get_file()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c60f1e19dceacf77749a6215b1fc77f758f46327/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L123), which says:

> By default the file at the url `origin` is downloaded to the
> cache_dir `~/.keras`, placed in the cache_subdir `datasets`,
> and given the filename `fname`. The final location of a file
> `example.txt` would therefore be `~/.keras/datasets/example.txt`.

So look in `C:\Users\My_User_Name\.keras\datasets`.